# how can you print the time and date in python

Tags: python, datetime

I really need to figure out how to print the date and time, and I do not need the `import time` function, please give me the shortest way possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/06/how-to-get-current-date-and-time-in/

Use what you Need from

```
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now()

print
print "Current date and time using str method of datetime object:"
print str(now)

print
print "Current date and time using instance attributes:"
print "Current year: %d" % now.year
print "Current month: %d" % now.month
print "Current day: %d" % now.day
print "Current hour: %d" % now.hour
print "Current minute: %d" % now.minute
print "Current second: %d" % now.second
print "Current microsecond: %d" % now.microsecond

print
print "Current date and time using strftime:"
print now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")

print
print "Current date and time using isoformat:"
print now.isoformat()
```

Answer (score 6):

You'll have to import something. I'd use datetime.

```
import datetime
## whatever code you want here
now = datetime.datetime.now()
print(now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"))
```

Comment: the code seems to work, thanks. but is there a way to separate the `import datetime` from the rest with other bits of code in between?

Comment: Usually all import statements go at the top of the code file. After importing datetime, you can then call it at any later time.

Comment: @RBXII3 Welcome to StackOverflow. If an answer helped you, please mark it as accepted so others can find and use it as well.

Answer (score 6):

What format or timezone do you want your date to be in?

If you want **local time**, import `time`:

```
import time
local_time = time.localtime()
time.strftime('%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S', local_time)
```

Output in local time:

```
'Fri, 07 Aug 2015 01:08:23'
```

For **UTC**, import `datetime`:

```
import datetime
utc_time = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
utc_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Output in UTC time:

```
'2015-08-07 05:06:58'
```